# Не видно svg иконку на вкладке страницы

Tags: html, css

хотелось бы узнать, почему не видно иконку на вкладке. Всё, в принципе, было хорошо видно, пока я не загрузила страницу на хост. Спасибо за внимание. [image: код,который я использовала]

Answer (score 0):

После переноса на хостинг, у вас изменился путь к папке `icons`.
Укажите корректный путь и иконка будет отображаться.

Comment: На телефоне отображается корректно, но на, допустим, ноутбуке, его нет.

Comment: Очистите историю браузера на ноутбуке